# ipython plotly can't create subplots

Tags: ipython, plotly

I'm trying to make a subplot with `plotly` but it's saying the tools module doesn't have a function called `make_subplots` even though it says to do that [here](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/subplots/). I'm quite confused.

```
from plotly import tools        # functions to help build plotly graphs
import plotly.plotly as py      # module that communicates with plotly 
from plotly.graph_objs import *
​
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=23, cols=2)
fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='')
​
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b8fb5b790a40> in <module>()
      3 from plotly.graph_objs import *
      4 
----> 5 fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=23, cols=2)
      6 fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'make_subplots'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your version of Plotly.